# Xcode6 elements in Interface Builder isn't shown on iOS device

Tags: swift, xcode6

I don't really suppose to get this error/bug, but it took place

I've created a project using swift for iPad, set Deployment Target to 7.0

IB: (last view have some UI elements)

[image]

But on iPad it shows a blank screen(the last view), the screen with two buttons shows normally. Simulator iOS shows as expected (right)

I use OS X Yosemite и Xcode 6.01

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have auto layout on you can get some weird results.

If you go to Editor>Resolve Auto Layout Issues> Update Frames, you might find that your UI elements aren't where Interface Builder shows them.

Comment: I can't really expect that to be a problem, but actually it is. Thanks!